# FHSTwitterEngine can't post a tweet with image

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I have referred the demo [**FHSTwitterEngine**](https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine) for posting tweets in iOS.

To post a tweet with image I have used this method,

```
- (NSError *)postTweet:(NSString *)tweetString withImageData:(NSData *)theData
```

It fails with `response.statusCode` as `403`.

The return data shows this message:

```
{"errors":[{"code":195,"message":"Missing or invalid url parameter"}]}
```

Parameters `tweetString` and `theData` passed are not `nil`.

if i only post text as original,it's succeed.

What could be the issue? Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine/blob/master/FHSTwitterEngine/FHSTwitterEngine.m

please, good luck!

====

I have referred the demo FHSTwitterEngine for posting tweets in iOS.

To post a tweet with image I have used this method,

- (NSError *)postTweet:(NSString *)tweetString withImageData:(NSData *)theData
  It fails with response.statusCode as 403.

The return data shows this message:

{"errors":[{"code":195,"message":"Missing or invalid url parameter"}]}
Parameters tweetString and theData passed are not nil.

if i only post text as original,it's succeed.

What could be the issue? Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Error say that you missed/invalid parameter of URL first check it? If make sure that you have to passed  all required parameter. then convert your URL string as legal URL. such like,

```
 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL_STRING"];
 NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

For more info about [stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a)

Comment: except changed "postTweet" to "postTweet withImageData",i don't change anything of this demo.so i think the URL string you asked is  @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json"

Comment: put this url in place of **URL_STRING**

Answer (score 0):

Try this for local image

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];

NSData *ImageData;//= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = img.image;

ImageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[ImageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];



if ([TxtField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    [[TwitterEngine sharedManager]postTweet:@"This is test image" withImageData:ImageData];

}
else
[[TwitterEngine sharedManager]postTweet:TxtField.text withImageData:ImageData];
```